# Union of "adjacent polylines that contain bezier curves"

Tags: algorithm, core-graphics, computational-geometry

Concrete example: take a map of European Countries, and a list of pointers to "the Paths that represent countries in the European Union", and output a single "Path representing the European Union".

e.g. if I have three input paths: red, green, and blue.

1. Red is made of straight line segments only
2. Green is made of line segments and beziers
3. Blue is made of beziers only

...then I need to create an output polyline-with-beziers that is the union of the three objects.

ADDITIONALLY, I need to cope with some error margin in the input data - c.f. the image below there are some very small "gaps" between the input shapes. In the image, the bottom figure (red) is the desired output.

[image]

This could easily go horribly wrong and take weeks of me failing to make it work. I'm trying to find a relatively simple approach which might be "good enough", but I'm currently stuck on:

1. How do you even begin to union Beziers?
2. What's a smart way of dealing with the "gaps" / error margin - I'm sure there's something cunning to do with simply rounding my float co-ordinates - but I can't see it :(

Finally ... target platform is iPhone - so I have access to all of Apple's Quartz / QuartzCore / CoreAnimation / etc. That provides *some* utility methods - but note: even Apple's *official* implementation of basics such as "does Path A intersect Path B?" are quite badly broken / incorrect in a lot of cases - so it's not very reliable :(.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA of how to achieve this (maybe) - but I don't know how to go about this either:

Perhaps ... instead calculate "the internal lines", and remove them, leaving me with something that's almost correct as "the path describing the union".

It could be quite badly wrong with my example Blue object, the point of intersection could give a badly-wrong curve - but it might be good enough.

To do this, I was thinking, maybe:

1. Take the convex hulls of each of the shapes
2. any line-segments *in the hulls* that overlap other hulls ... are "internal"
3. ... reading-back to the points in the original shape that created each hull-line-segment (OR were invalidated by that segment) ... those points are "internal to the union"

?

Comment: Convex hulls make no sense in the context of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know how to do a union of polygonal shapes. I assume you know that, if not you have to learn it first.

Now you can tesselate your curves, find the polygonal union, and fit pieces of original curved back into the union. You will have to adjust the intersection points slightly, from straight line intersections to curve intersections, but the adjustments will be small and you can find them with a simple iterative approximation algorithm.

To cope with errors, offset your polygons by a pisitive amount before the union, and offset the result by a negative amount before fitting the curve pieces.

Sorry, can't type much more on this phone :-(

Comment: Offsetting the polygons? How does that work? Maybe you meant "offset each line segment along the line from origin to the mid point of segment" ? Scaling them works as a first approximation - if you have purely convex polys - but fails on concave polys.

Comment: Ofsetting is basically a Minkowski sum with a disc, it's a fairly standard operation, look up "polygon offset". It is normally implemented like this: move each segment in the direction perpendicular to the segment itself, all by the same distance, and recompute the intersection points. There are libraries that have this operation. Scaling indeed won't work.

Comment: "polygon offset" - most hits are for OpenGL, which defines it as I'd expect (single translation applied to all points), but I found some hits for "inward/outward polygon offset" which did the track, thanks